# arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: permission denied error

Tags: 12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 X64
I'm facing problem in permission, I have installed sourcery codebench and when i access it like

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
```

it says root/opt/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: permission denied
 While the same code is running in Ubuntu 11.10 x32
Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the problem solved.
Need to install ia32libs.
Use following command to install ia32libs.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

if fails then run this Command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```